# Differences between list == [] or list.isEmpty Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable `list` of `type List<Something>` with this statement :

```
if (list==[]) print("list is empty");
else if (list.isEmpty) print("The previous check didn't work so I used this one").
```

I thought these 2 lines were exactly the same code, which are the differences? Why `list==[]` is different from `list.isEmpty` ?

Answer (score 1):

First variant checks if list is the same instance as newly creted instance (created via [] - so it is reference comparison) - therefore it is false. `List.isEmpty` on the other hand, "asks" the given list if it is empty or not.